# How to process video files in batch using Emotion SDK for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video, affdex-sdk

I am using Affectiva's Emotion SDK for Javascript to play and analyze a video file. Currently, I am playing the video as a stream and capturing emotion features following their ["Analyze a video frame stream"](https://knowledge.affectiva.com/v3.2/docs/analyze-a-video-frame-stream-4) tutorial. However, I want to process the video file in batch rather than taking the whole duration of the video to analyze.

Increasing the playback rate of the video helped speed up this processes. I have also tried to skip frames by seeking ahead in the video but the performance was disappointing. Does anyone know of a way to process the video file that isn't bottlenecked by the playback rate of the video?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. Did you figure this out? You can refer to the youtube-demo which certainly is related to what you are trying to achieve : https://github.com/Affectiva/youtube-demo

Comment: Thank you for the reference Umang. I have it figured out but I will look at this implementation for any insights!

Comment: @kkawabat, could you please describe your solution or post some sample code?  The link above isn't much help, since the demo plays a YouTube video, but analyzes the webcam.  I'm having trouble getting FrameDetector to work in a browser, so an alternative solution would be a big help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646782/debugging-affectiva-framedetector-worker-code-reported-an-exception

Comment: Hi Capiediem, I used the original method of skipping frames a bit more efficiently to achieve my purpose. I have posted my jsfiddle code below. Simply upload a video using "choose file" button and it should run automatically. It's technically not a "batch" processes as I specified in the question but it was able to run faster than the duration of the video when fps is set lower and the visualizer video is disabled. The script also downloads a csv file of the the metrics from affectiva after the video is analyzed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem (albeit probably not very efficient) by using seeking with a lower fps. Essentially in the detector's "onImageResultsSuccess" function, I call the function nextFrame which skips ahead in the video by an amount I set with the variable fps. Which calls the "seeked" event on the video element which can then call the captureImage function that triggers the detector creating a loop that runs until the whole video is analyzed. Below is a portion of the code as well as jsfiddle implementation.

```
  var nextFrame = function() {
    // when frame is captured, increase
    vidTimeStamp = vidTimeStamp + (1 / fps);
    // if we are not passed end, seek to next interval
    if (vidTimeStamp <= video.duration) {
      // this will trigger another seeked event
      message_text.innerHTML = ((vidTimeStamp / video.duration) * 100).toFixed(2) + "% completed";
      video.currentTime = vidTimeStamp;
    } else {
      // DONE!, next action
      message_text.innerHTML = "100% Completed";
      alert("Video Processed");

      download_btn.click();
    }
  };

  video.addEventListener("seeked", function(e) {
    // now video has seeked and current frames will show
    // at the time as we expect
    captureImage(vidTimeStamp);
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkawabat/zvt9rbve/