# Debugging Affectiva FrameDetector: Worker Code Reported an Exception

Tags: affdex-sdk

I'm trying to use [FrameDetector](https://knowledge.affectiva.com/docs/analyze-a-video-frame-stream-4) to process an existing MP4 file.  I've put the video file and the HTML/JavaScript below inside a node.js server and run it at localhost, so there shouldn't be aby CORS issues.

The detector starts correctly, but when I send image data to it, the same two things happen every time:

1. The first request returns an empty `faces` array
2. The second request returns an error (with a unique, trailing number each time): `worker code reported an exception14920304`.

I'm not really sure what to do with that message- does anyone have any suggestions?

```
//- FrameDetector.pug
html
  head
    title FrameDetector Demo
    script(src='https://download.affectiva.com/js/3.2/affdex.js')
  body
    canvas#canvas
    video#video-to-analyze(preload="auto" controls="true")
      source(type="video/mp4" src="video/my-video.mp4")
    script(src='js/FrameDetector.js')
```

and

```
// FrameDetector.js
var heartbeat, startTimestamp;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var v = document.getElementById('video-to-analyze');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth / 100);
  var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight / 100);
  canvas.width = cw;
  canvas.height = ch;

  v.addEventListener('play', function(){
      draw(this,context,cw,ch);
  },false);

},false);

function draw(v,c,w,h) {
  if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
  c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
  setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
}







function analyzeVideoFrame() {
  //Get a canvas element from DOM
  var aCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = aCanvas.getContext('2d');

  //Get imageData object.
  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 360);
  console.log("Captured imageData.", imageData);

  //Get current time in seconds
  var now = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;

  //Get delta time between the first frame and the current frame.
  var deltaTime = now - startTimestamp;

  //Process the frame
  detector.process(imageData, deltaTime);
}

function onImageResultsSuccess(faces, image, timestamp) {
  console.log("onImageResultsSuccess:", timestamp, faces.length, faces[0]);
}

function onImageResultsFailure(image, timestamp, err_detail) {
  console.error("onImageResultsFailure:", timestamp, err_detail);
  clearInterval(heartbeat);
}



if (typeof(affdex)=="undefined") {
  console.log("The affdex global variable has not been loaded.");
}

var detector = new affdex.FrameDetector(affdex.FaceDetectorMode.LARGE_FACES);

detector.detectAllExpressions();
detector.detectAllEmotions();
detector.detectAllAppearance();

detector.addEventListener("onInitializeSuccess", function() {
  document.getElementById('video-to-analyze').play();
  startTimestamp = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
  heartbeat = setInterval(analyzeVideoFrame, 1000);
});
detector.addEventListener("onInitializeFailure", function() {
  console.error("Affectiva failed to initialize.");
});

detector.addEventListener("onImageResultsSuccess", onImageResultsSuccess);
detector.addEventListener("onImageResultsFailure", onImageResultsFailure);

detector.start();
```

Output in the console:

```
Captured imageData. ImageData {data: Uint8ClampedArray(921600), width: 640, height: 360}
onImageResultsSuccess: 0.005000114440917969 0 undefined
Captured imageData. ImageData {data: Uint8ClampedArray(921600), width: 640, height: 360}
onImageResultsFailure: 0.0009999275207519531 worker code reported an exception14920304
```

Comment: FYI, I've also posted here: http://discuss.affectiva.com/t/worker-code-reported-an-exception/389

Comment: I just realized that the data attribute of the ImageData sent to the SDK was mostly empty.  The first 12 attributes of the array had integer values, but the remaining 921,588 elements were all zero.  Probably an issue with drawing to the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  Once I got the image drawn correctly to the canvas element, the Affectiva code worked fine.  Here's a my corrected code:

```
//- FrameDetector.pug
html
  head
    title FrameDetector Demo
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='https://download.affectiva.com/js/3.2/affdex.js')
  body
    canvas#canvas(width="640" height="360" style="display:none;")
    video#video(preload="auto" controls="true")
      source(type="video/mp4" src="video/my-video.mp4")
    script(src='js/FrameDetector.js')
```

and

```
// FrameDetector.js
var heartbeat, startTimestamp;

function onVideoPlay() {
  var $this = this; //cache
  (function loop() {
    if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
      ctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0);
      setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
    }
  })();
}

function analyzeVideoFrame() {
  //Get a canvas element from DOM
  var aCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = aCanvas.getContext('2d');


  //Get imageData object.
  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 360);
  console.log("Captured imageData.", imageData);

  //Get current time in seconds
  var now = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;

  //Get delta time between the first frame and the current frame.
  var deltaTime = now - startTimestamp;

  //Process the frame
  detector.process(imageData, deltaTime);
}

function onImageResultsSuccess(faces, image, timestamp) {
  console.log("onImageResultsSuccess:", timestamp, faces.length, faces[0]);
}

function onImageResultsFailure(image, timestamp, err_detail) {
  console.error("onImageResultsFailure:", timestamp, err_detail);
  clearInterval(heartbeat);
}


$(function() {
  if (typeof(affdex)=="undefined") {
    console.log("The affdex global variable has not been loaded.");
  }

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var detector = new affdex.FrameDetector(affdex.FaceDetectorMode.LARGE_FACES);

  // Set up a loop to draw frames to the canvas element
  video.addEventListener('play', onVideoPlay, 0);


  // Set up and start the detector
  detector.detectAllExpressions();
  detector.detectAllEmotions();
  detector.detectAllAppearance();

  detector.addEventListener("onInitializeSuccess", function() {
    document.getElementById('video').play();
    startTimestamp = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
    heartbeat = setInterval(analyzeVideoFrame, 1000);
  });
  detector.addEventListener("onInitializeFailure", function() {
    console.error("Affectiva failed to initialize.");
  });

  detector.addEventListener("onImageResultsSuccess", onImageResultsSuccess);
  detector.addEventListener("onImageResultsFailure", onImageResultsFailure);

  detector.start();
});
```